# Android - JSON Parse Not Showing Data using "setText"

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following JSON Information.

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "locations": [{
        "id": "750",
        "geo": {
            "name": "Lord Howe Island",
            "state": "Lord Howe Island",
            "country": {
                "id": "au",
                "name": "Australia"
            },
            "latitude": -31.557,
            "longitude": 159.086
        },
        "astronomy": {
            "objects": [{
                "name": "moon",
                "days": [{
                    "date": "2018-09-05",
                    "events": [],
                    "moonphase": "waningcrescent"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

What I wish to do is print to a textView just a few details in the JSON (Not All), so my desired output is the following:

Name: Lord Howe Island 
Country: Australia 
Moon Phase: Waning Crescent

However, I do not have any luck when parsing the information to be printed in the textView. I am currently using the following code:

```
JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            JSONObject geo = JO.getJSONObject("geo");
            JSONObject astronomy = JO.getJSONObject("astronomy");
            singleParsed = "Name:" + geo.get("name") + "\n" +
                    "Latitude:" + JO.get("latitude") + "\n" +
                    "Longitude:" + JO.get("longitude") + "\n" +
                    "Phase: " + astronomy.get("moonphase") + "\n";
        }
```

Then showing the data with the following:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        MainActivity.fetcheddata.setText(this.singleParsed);


    }
}
```

I can print all of the data just using

```
MainActivity.fetcheddata.setText(this.data);
```

However I do also see the tags in the textView and ALL Information, not the few tags I am after.

What Am I doing wrong?

All help is much appreciated

Edit: This was suggested, currently working on it.

```
JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            JSONObject astronomy = JO.getJSONObject("astronomy");
            JSONArray objects = astronomy.getJSONArray("objects");
            JSONArray days = objects.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("days");
            Object moonphase = days.getJSONObject(0).get("moonphase");

            moon = "Name:" + days.get(Integer.parseInt("moonphase"));
        }
```

Comment: Is your data variable being set to your result.locations?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you saying that `this.singleParsed` is containing ALL the data? or maybe none?

Comment: When using this.SingleParsed, No data appears. Data only appears when using this.data.

Comment: so either your code is not getting called, or it is incorrect - debug it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is you're trying to use JSONObjects, even though locations is an array, as is objects.

For this to work, you will need to iterate over the array as such:

```
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(yourData);
    JSONArray locations = jo.getJSONArray("locations");

    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length(); ++i) {
        //iterate over each key, etc.
    }
```

In my opinion, at the end of the day, this will be a mess, and a pain to maintain if you change keys, add keys, etc. I'd recommend looking into something like GSON, and then creating just viewmodels of the data you want. In the end you would end up with something as such:

```
List<T> yourObjects = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, X[].class);
```

Then you can individually access any property you want.

Answer (score 0):

cannot get `moonphase` directly from `astronomy` ,    `[]` will define an array, so you could do like this:

```
            "astronomy": {
                "objects": [{
                    "name": "moon",
                    "days": [{
                        "date": "2018-09-05",
                        "events": [],
                        "moonphase": "waningcrescent"
                    }]
                }]
            }
JSONObject astronomy = JO.getJSONObject("astronomy");
JSONArray objects = astronomy.getJSONArray("objects");
JSONArray days = objects.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("days");
JSONObject moonphase = days.getJSONObject(0).get("moonphase");
```

Comment: Please see updated answer for more information. Is this what you are suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: so I still don't understanding why somebody downnote me :(

Comment: yes, downnote canceled. maybe I should write more detailed answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json data as it is and your output as you wrote above:

```
    JSONArray locations = data.getJSONArray("location");
    JSONObject loc = locations.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject geo = loc.getJSONObject("geo");

    JSONObject country = geo.getJSONObject("country");

    JSONObject astronomy = loc.getJSONObject("astronomy");
    JSONObject objects = astronomy.getJSONArray("objects").getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject day = objects.getJSONArray("days").getJSONObject(0);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String singleParsed = "Name:" + geo.getString("name") + "\n" +
            "Country: " + country.getString("name") +
            "Moon Phase: " + astronomy.getString("moonphase") + "\n";
```

Comment: Additionally, it's easier if you use GSON to parse such data